# How to render component dynamically in React Native

Tags: typescript, react-native

I have custom tab control in React Native app, which is rendered by dynamic config, like:

```
const TABS = [
   { title: 'Tab 1', component: MyComponentOne },
   { title: 'Tab 2', component: MyComponentTwo }
];
```

`title` property goes for tab title, and when the tab is selected, I need to render the corresponding component into the `Animated.FlatList`.

How can I render `MyComponentOne` and `MyComponentTwo` dynamically, instead of doing?:

```
if (typeof item.component === 'MyComponentOne') return <MyComponentOne />
if (typeof item.component === 'MyComponentTwo') return <MyComponentTwo />
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You can have an object mapping e.g. the tab title to the component and then get the component you want to render based on the title from that object.

```js
const components: Record<string, React.ReactNode> = {
  "Tab 1": <MyComponent/>,
  "Tab 2": <MyOtherComponent/>
}
```

Here an working example, obviously in JS. But you can just add the types and it will work.

```js
const components = {
  "Tab 1": <MyComponent/>,
  "Tab 2": <MyOtherComponent/>,
  "Tab 3": <YetAnotherComponent/>
}

function MyComponent(){
  return (
      <div class="component my">
        MyComponent
      </div>
  )
}

function MyOtherComponent(){
  return (
      <div class="component other">
        MyOtherComponent
      </div>
  )
}

function YetAnotherComponent(){
  return (
      <div class="component yetanother">
        YetAnotherComponent
      </div>
  )
}

function TabComponent(){
  const [activeTab, setActiveTab] = React.useState("Tab 1");

  return (
      <div class="tabcomponent">
        <div class="tabs">
            <button class="tab" onClick={() => setActiveTab("Tab 1")}>
              Tab 1
            </button>
            <button class="tab" onClick={() => setActiveTab("Tab 2")}>
              Tab 2
            </button>
            <button class="tab" onClick={() => setActiveTab("Tab 3")}>
              Tab 3
            </button>
        </div>
          {components[activeTab]}
      </div>
  );
}
ReactDOM.render(<TabComponent/>, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```css
.tabcomponent {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.tabs {
  display: flex;
  flex-grow: 1;
}

.tab {
  flex-grow: 1;
  flex-basis: 100%;
}

.component {
  height: 50px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.my {
  background-color: red;
}

.other {
  background-color: yellow;
}

.yetanother {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@18/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@18/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```